# Password Validation - Spaces

Tags: c++

**Problem:**
Will not exit the loop.

I have check a million sites, and can not figure out how to get this implemented. This loop will not exit because of the getline(). Do I need a cin.ignore() or cin.clear()? I can not get it to work after trying every derivation possible. Please help..

```
while (strlen(u.username) < 6 || strlen(u.username) > 18||got_space==true)
{
    got_space = false;
    cout << "\nError: Your username must be between 6 and 18 characters long and have no spaces. Please try again. (Press e to exit)\n";
    cin >> u.username;
    if (strlen(u.username)<2 && tolower(u.username[0]) == 'e')
    {
        return;
    }
    cin.getline(u.username, USERNAME_SIZE); // Find whitespaces

    for (int c = 0; c < strlen(u.username); c++) // Check for spaces
    {
        if (isspace(u.username[c]))
        {
            got_space = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use std::string. For one thing, if you are handling passwords, you probably want secure code. It's harder to make a bug such as buffer overrun with strings.

Comment: I'm also curious what the significance of entering "e" as the username is.

Comment: What is std:: anything because i see it for a lot of solutions online, but my teacher said dont use it right now, at least until my get better in c++ coding..??

Comment: @NeilKirk if someone types 1 letter and it is `e` then the program returns... Not the best way to go about it.

Comment: I am making Blackjack, for every input prompt i give the user the option to exit to the previous menu. All my function are pretty much a menu

Comment: @user3672451, you should tell your teacher that there is a difference between C and C++ ... Also, you should test if all letters are in a valid range. Or should `\b`, `\xA0` and the BOM be a valid input?

Comment: Interesting because std::string is easier to use than C strings so why wouldn't you learn that first.

Comment: 'Just an exit command

Comment: I dont know what they will teach in the second C++ class, but she even encourages, at least for now, using arrays vs. vectors

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can you please post the error messages, or if there are no errors, then maybe post a desired result.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I got caught up in the comments. Your problem lies here `while(strlen(u.username) < 6 || strlen(u.username) > 18||got_space==true)` if any of those conditions are `true`, then the loop will continue going.

Comment: If I type in six 1's (or whatever in the range 6-18 characters), it will not exit no matter what

Comment: If could either step through your program or print out each tested character with `cout << (int) u.username[c] << endl;`.

Comment: Agree with Kay, the best thing we can teach you here is that debugging is your friend. At the end of the while look print out each of the conditions and see which one is still true. That will be the best guide as to what is going on

Comment: Typing in "1 1" gives me 32 and 49 (space in the middle)

Comment: That is after i put the "cout << (int)u.username[c] << endl;" line.

Comment: What does "1111111" (7 ones with no spaces) output?

Comment: It doesnt output anything, just the error message again

Comment: If i do two 2's with five spaces in the middle. e.g. "2     2", it gives me five 32's and one 50 at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were typing the username into the `cin` that checked if `e` was pressed and also typing into the `cin.getline(...)`. I came to this conclusion when you commented that

> Typing in "1 1" gives me 32 and 49 (space in the middle)

Typing in `"1 1"` should have resulted with the ints `49` `32` `49` being output. Because you cast your characters to int's in the ouput statement. In ASCII the character `1` is equivalent to the integer `49`, the character `' '`<sub>(blank space)</sub> is equivalent to the integer `32`. Since you stated that you typed "1 1" and only got 32 and 49, I'm lead to believe that your started typing the username into the first `cin` and continued onto the next. Here is a fix:

```
while (strlen(u.username) < 6 || strlen(u.username) > 18||got_space==true)
{
    got_space = false;
    cout << "\nError: Your username must be between 6 and 18 "
         << "characters long and have no spaces. "
         << "Please try again. (Press e then enter to exit)\n";

    // remove this cin because it's messing up your code
    // cin >> u.username;

    // move the cin.getline(...) to here
    cin.getline(u.username, USERNAME_SIZE); // Find whitespaces        

    if (strlen(u.username)<2 && tolower(u.username[0]) == 'e')
    {
        return;
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < strlen(u.username); c++) // Check for spaces
    {
        if (isspace(u.username[c]))
        {
            got_space = true;
        }
    }
}
```

If this code runs and you run into a memory-leak or segmentation fault then the error cannot be found with the code that has been posted and more code will be needed, as in all of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it has been tagged as C++, so let's do with C++ ways.

1. I prefer to use string::size() rather than strlen() (for C-style string)
2. To find space in a string we can use string::find().

The following is a function for validating username input:

```
const unsigned validate(std::string& uname) {
    const unsigned s = uname.size();

    if(s < 6 || s > 18) return 1; 
    if(uname.find(" ") != std::string::npos) return 2;
    return 0;
}
```